# instalacion de android en ubuntu

Tags: android-studio

hola a todos primera vez que uso este foro. por favor me podrian ayudar, lo que sucede es que quiero instalar android studio en ubuntu
se necesitan estos  comandos.
*instalacion de JDK
sudo apt-get install default-jre

*instalacion de ADB y FASTBOOT
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb adb android-tools-fastboot fastboot

y otros mas, el punto es que me vota este error amigos.

dpkg: error al limpiar:
 el subproceso instalado paquete apport script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 2
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.20.10-0ubuntu27.3_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

por favor saquenme de este lio gracias.